# Does rethinkDB support an in clause?

Tags: rethinkdb

I couldn't find in the documentation anything about an in clause in rethink.

Does rethink support the equivelent of mongo's $in clause?  i.e. row('name').in(['bob', 'tom']) ?

I suppose you can chain a bunch of "or" clauses but that seems clunky.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RethinkDB doesn't have `in`, but it has `contains`. The order, therefore is in reverse to `in`. You can write like:

```
r.expr(['bob', 'tom']).contains(row('name'))
```

Example,

```
r.expr([1,2,3,4]).contains(1)
=> true
r.expr([1,2,3,4]).contains(5)
=> false
```

Another real life example, find an user whose name in an array. Let's create some sample data:

```
r.tableCreate('test')
r.table('test').insert([{name: 'foo'}, {name: 'bar'}, {name: 'foobar'}])
```

With above data, I can find all document whose `name` in an array:

```
r.table('test').filter(function(doc) {
    return r.expr(['foo', 'bar']).contains(doc('name'))
})
```

Comment: cool, also saw in the sql cheatsheet that you can use `r.table("users") .get_all("Peter", "John",index="name")` if there is an index

Comment: also does this support changes monitoring?  I tried to put .changes after the filter and it threw an error.

Comment: Yes, `filter` supports `changes`. Which exact query did you use and what was the error?